# Calendar control for xPage

Tags: xpages

I'm looking for Calendar Control (just like a classic Lotus Notes view), with few base options like: 1 week, 1 months, 1 day and some another etc.

I've found 2 on openntf.org + I've fond something similar on dojox 1.6. We do not use ExtLib so I need something easy to deploy.

any suggestions? thanks in advance!

// Dmytro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin that provides a full-sized, drag & drop calendar like the one below. It uses AJAX to fetch events on-the-fly for each month and is easily configured to use your own feed format (an extension is provided for Google Calendar). It is visually customizable and exposes hooks for user-triggered events (like clicking or dragging an event). It is open source and dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/